# Regex to find all '?' without "<?", "?>"

Tags: php, regex

I'm restoring UTF-8 characters after changing encoding of PHP project's files. I'm trying to find all files that need to be changed with regular expression. Regex should work like:

1. Find any word contains `?`
2. But exclude `<?`, `?>`, and `php?`

I have tried to construct regular expression on my own, but I really have no idea how to force regex to find 'something' previously excluding matches with specific words. How I can achieve that?

EDIT:

Since there was few questions about it - why exclude "php?"? In my case, it is always beginning of the GET url, for example example.php?id=10

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html usually. Not sure that's useful in your case and that botched encoding issue - unless those are literal question marks.

Comment: This is not a good idea but maybe something like https://regex101.com/r/eJZ3oM/1/ could do it. Why should `php?` be ignored? If it is multibyte characters you might have split them and then this will get worse.

Comment: @mario - Yes, those are literal question marks. And i have tried this link too. But still - i don't know how to make regex to first search for negative lookbehind and THEN positive one.

Comment: @user3783243 it's because question mark behind php is always GET url in my case. Beside thanks for your idea, but for example for "<? ?pgp ?>" it is not working

Comment: Why would you need to exclude `php?` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this Regex works:

```
(?<!\bphp)(?<!<)\?(?!>)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yBYHFI/1)

Explanation:

using 2 negative lookbehinds:

1. `\bphp`
2. `<`

and 1 negative look ahead for `>`

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer - is `(?)` the whole expression?

Comment: It is working! Using negative look behind in all cases made me understand how this is working and how to use it. Thank you :)